# Unable to update to existing value in DynamoDb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamodb with key as word and value as cou. word is my hash key and cou is the attribute key. I am trying to update one of my word value to another value. I am getting this exception.

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

What I am doing is in the below code. Any suggestions.

```
java.util.Map<String, AttributeValue> item = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
            item.put("word", new AttributeValue().withS("TimeZone"));

            java.util.Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
            expressionAttributeValues.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withN("1"));
            expressionAttributeValues.put(":val2", new AttributeValue().withN("12"));

            ReturnValue returnValues = ReturnValue.ALL_NEW;

            UpdateItemRequest updateItemRequest = new UpdateItemRequest()
                .withTableName(tableName)
                .withKey(item)
                .withUpdateExpression("add cou :val1 set NewAttribute=:val2")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues)
                .withReturnValues(returnValues);       

            UpdateItemResult result = client.updateItem(updateItemRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that "word" is your has key and "cou" is you "attribute key". I assume by attribute key you mean range key. If you have both a hash and range key in your schema, you need to specify both in the key hashmap ("items"), you can't update with the hash key alone.

Comment: Exactly. I have made my "cou" as range key and when I modified it then i did not get any error regarding the schema. It was solved. Thanks.